# jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Exceeded maximum depth for nested request dispatches: 20

Tags: java-ee, jsp, servlet

Помогите пожалуйста. Уже 2 дня страдаю. Когда в моем сервлете вот такой шаблон  `urlPatterns = {"/sample"}` (без *) и вот такой URL `/sample?col=20` - все работает прекрасно

но когда я решил изменить шаблон `urlPatterns = {"/sample/*"}` что б ловить такой URL `/sample/Tom-Sawyer?col=20`
Я стал получать ошибку "jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Exceeded maximum depth for nested request dispatches: 20"

Вот мой сервлет

```
@WebServlet(name = "Sample",  urlPatterns = {"/sample/*"})
public class SampleController extends HttpServlet {
   @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        long col =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("col"));

    ... some Business logic ...

       RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/sample.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Возможно есть конфликт с моим фильтром:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "EndsWith", urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class TypeFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        if (request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/book")) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/book").forward(request, response);
        }
        else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Остальные сервлеты имеют строгий вид urlPatterns = {"/некоторое_имя"}

Но что самое возмутительное, в попытке отсеить причины, для URL `/sample/Tom-Sawyer` я делал `urlPatterns = {"/sample/Tom-Sawyer"}` т.е. точный и? 404 ошибка! Почему! Я убирал дефис /sample/tomsawyer - и паттерн такой же = 404 ошибка! Что происходит, в прошлом проекте сервлет так себя не вел. На Jakarta какая-то дичь началась. Или я что-то упустил?

Servlet 5, Jakarta EE9, JSP

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю почему, но если поставить слеш перед WEB-INF `request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/sample.jsp"`, то все работает

Но если шаблон `urlPatterns = {"/sample"}` то работает и без слеша  `request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/sample.jsp"`